# to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to route HttpServletRequest to another microservice where request may contain multi-part request or any normal request. but while sending I am getting the below error.

Note: I dont want to modify the request as I am trying to write some generic method.

```
public Object doPostCall(HttpServletRequest request, String requestURL, String rootURL)
            throws URISyntaxException, IOException, ServletException {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final String url = rootURL + requestURL;
        uri = new URI(url);

        try {
            result2 = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, Object.class);
            System.out.println("after service call" + result2);
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result2;
    }
```

**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException**:

```
No serializer found for class java.util.Collections$3 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest["request"]->org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper["request"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["attributeNames"])
```

**Even I have tried setting this in property file.** `spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false`, but it didn't work

**My Consume controller is like below:**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/upload/{moduleName}/{fileType}", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFiles(@RequestPart("file") List<MultipartFile> inputFileList,
            @RequestParam(value = "createdBy", required = false) String createdBy, @PathVariable String moduleName,
            @RequestParam(value = "catalogId", required = false) String catalogId,
            @RequestParam(value = "catalogName", required = false) String catalogName, @PathVariable String fileType) {
```

Comment: What JVM and what version of Jackson are you using? This sounds like a very old Jackson version is having trouble with the new convenience types in `Collections`

Comment: Java 8 and Spring boot version 2.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: why return as `Object`?

Comment: try to serialize as String instead of Object

Comment: Tried like below 

`String stringResult = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, String.class)`

Still getting the same error:

**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.util.Collections$3 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)**  - [M.Navy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8166506/m-navy)

Comment: @Deadpool String also having the same issue.

Comment: For me setting this property spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false worked just fine

Answer (score 3):

Try annotating your entity class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties("hibernateLazyInitializer")`